# Getting PATH NOT FOUND while reading WAV media from remote storage

Tags: windows, windows-7

We facing  a weird issue on our network with Win 7 pro clients while using media app that reads  from 
 remote storage (Netapp) on 1 Gig infra WAV format.

While playing from app we getting from time to time Network Path not found error on the app itself.

After i did some wireshark traces and didn't found any indication for network congestion , i did 
fileMon trace from Sysinternals suite and found some weired notification as showing below.

My question did anyone faced same issue and those event could help me debug situation

Please advice

Thanks

```
Date & Time:    9/3/2013 6:12:52 PM
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  CreateFile
Result: CSC OBJECT PATH NOT FOUND
Path:   \\na-broadcast\dalet\storage\SPLIT_Audio_10
TID:    1400
Duration:   0.0005625
Desired Access: Read Attributes, Synchronize
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Synchronous IO Non-Alert
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete
AllocationSize: n/a
Impersonating:  S-1-5-21-879982391-1912835863-728211738-1124
```

and

```
Date & Time:    9/3/2013 6:14:20 PM
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  FileSystemControl
Result: PATH NOT FOUND
Path:   \\na-broadcast\dalet\storage\SPLIT_Audio_10
TID:    5708
Duration:   0.0000206
Control:    CSC_FSCTL_OPERATION_QUERY_HANDLE
```

Comment: Try it with offline files and folders disabled and see if it still happens.

Comment: Hi Gregg,

Its  works  ,Thank  you very much

I saw that Offline files is enabled by default how come its happen, is it only happen if someone set the offline folder to cache files?

Thanks again

Cheers

Comment: I don't know, it was just a lucky guess! :)  I just knew those CSC calls related to that functionality.